# android Keyevent: long press and normal press (not able to make it work as wanted)

Tags: android

I am trying to create a left key press action for my TV app.

My remote has left/right up and down keys

I want to run two different function when normal press and long press.

I am trying the following

If I press long press it just does the action of normal press more times.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                if (event.isLongPress()) {
                    goBackward();
                    return true;
                }else{
                    goBackward2();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

How can I do this.

NOT ABLE TO SUCCEED AS BELOW ALSO

```
    boolean leftDownLongPressed = false;

    boolean rightDownLongPressed = false;


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.isLongPress()) {
                    goBackward();
                    leftDownLongPressed = true;
                    return true;
                }

                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !event.isLongPress()) {
                    if(!leftDownLongPressed){
                        goBackward2();
                        leftDownLongPressed=false;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATED (2023-01-18)

As OP updated the question and he wants to have more than one DPAD key to have the same logic, we will then need to memorize all the key press start time instead of a single one.

So the solution is simple as it is based on previous example to modify, just replace the instance variable `mKeyDownStartTime` to a Map.

**Example (Remove previous example implementation before you try the code below)**

```
    ...
    // An instance map var, key=${key code pressed}, value=${key down start time}
    Map<Integer, Long> mKeyIdToKeyDownStartTsMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Step 1: Pass the keyCode and action to keyEventAction()
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        int action = event.getAction();
        
        keyEventAction(keyCode, action);
        
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    // Step 2: Switch between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, call corresponding methods
    private void keyEventAction(int keyCode, int action) {
        switch (action) {
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startKeyDown(keyCode);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                endKeyDown(keyCode);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Step 3: Logic for action down, just similar to previous but we will store the data to the instance map now
    private void startKeyDown(int key) {
        @Nullable Long keyDownStartTs = mKeyIdToKeyDownStartTsMap.get(key);
        if (keyDownStartTs == null) {
            keyDownStartTs = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            Log.d(TAG, "startKeyDown: key down start, add data to map [ " +
                    "key=" + KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(key) +
                    ", value=" + keyDownStartTs +
                    " ]");

            mKeyIdToKeyDownStartTsMap.put(key, keyDownStartTs);
        }
        // Else keyDownStartTs already recorded for the DPAD key, ignore the logic here
    }

    // Step 4: Logic for action up
    private void endKeyDown(int key) {
        @Nullable Long keyDownStartTs = mKeyIdToKeyDownStartTsMap.get(key);
        if (keyDownStartTs != null) { // True indicates that the start key down time has been recorded for the [key]
            long endKeyDownTs = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            // Remove the kvp in mapping to allow the start time can be set again in the map for the [key]
            mKeyIdToKeyDownStartTsMap.remove(key);

            long pressDuration = endKeyDownTs - keyDownStartTs;

            Log.d(TAG, "endKeyDown: [ keyPressDuration=" + pressDuration + " ]");

            if (pressDuration > 5000) {
                Log.d(TAG, "endKeyDown: LONG press of " + KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(key) + " detected");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "endKeyDown: SHORT press of " + KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(key) + " detected");
            }
        }
        // Else keyDownStartTs has never been recorded for the key pressed, ignore the logic here
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
D/PlaygroundActivity: startKeyDown: key down start, add data to map [ key=KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, value=25132778 ]
D/PlaygroundActivity: endKeyDown: [ keyPressDuration=6963 ]
D/PlaygroundActivity: endKeyDown: LONG press of KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT detected

D/PlaygroundActivity: startKeyDown: key down start, add data to map [ key=KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN, value=26550861 ]
D/PlaygroundActivity: endKeyDown: [ keyPressDuration=2046 ]
D/PlaygroundActivity: endKeyDown: SHORT press of KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN detected

D/PlaygroundActivity: startKeyDown: key down start, add data to map [ key=KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, value=26554383 ]
D/PlaygroundActivity: endKeyDown: [ keyPressDuration=1403 ]
D/PlaygroundActivity: endKeyDown: SHORT press of KEYCODE_DPAD_UP detected
```

---

By observation, when a DPAD key is pressing, multiple times of key down events are dispatched. (i.e., discrete events of key down)

So in order to detect a long press of `KEY_CODE_DPAD_LEFT`, you will need to calculate the duration by yourself. And then determine how long a button pressed is **long** to you. (e.g., 5 seconds)

To calculate the duration, you will need to detect:

1. When do someone press the key
2. When do someone leave the key

I believe both the overide methods `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` have the ability to do so, so here is an example that I have just written.

**Example**

- To detect key down start time (`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT`), we will need an instance variable

```
    long mKeyDownStartTime = 0;
    
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
            startKeyDown(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void startKeyDown(long startKeyDownTime) {
        if (mKeyDownStartTime == 0) { // this is added to prevent identical discrete key down event reset the value
            mKeyDownStartTime = startKeyDownTime;
        }
    }
```

- To calculate the key down duration WHEN key up event occurs

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
            endKeyDown(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void endKeyDown(long endKeyDownTime) {
        long pressDuration = endKeyDownTime - mKeyDownStartTime;
        mKeyDownStartTime = 0; // reset to zero to allow startKeyDown() set the value in again
        Log.d(TAG, "endKeyDown: [ keyPressDuration=" + pressDuration + " ]");

        if (pressDuration > 5000) {
            Log.d(TAG, "endKeyDown: LONG press of DPAD_LEFT detected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "endKeyDown: SHORT press of DPAD_LEFT detected");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi I have edited my question added one more way i was trying. Its not working. Can you suggest anyway to work that way

Comment: Dispatch key events will also not work for long press detection in remote DPAD. So may I ask the objective first? I assume that you want the long press key detection for all DPAD (LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN), right?

Comment: the problem is i press down and long press and then release then the action takes place as per your solution

where as if i press down and long press i want the action to happen.